# Adding amounts from unrelated tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables;
TableA:

```
id  amount
1   50
```

TableB:

```
id  amount
1   10
2   20
```

These three tables are not not related in anyway but I want a sum of the amount in each table and then the sum of all amounts in all tables to do that I used the query below.

```
SELECT sum(A.amount) AS a, SUM(B.amount) AS b,  CONCAT(A.amount + B.amount + C.amount) as c FROM A, B
```

And this gives the result:

```
a    b    c
100  30  80
```

The Result I am looking for is

```
a    b    c
50   30   80
```

Kindly let me know what I am not doing right.

Comment: You've missed the table definition / data for tablec, but i assume its similar to `tablea` and `tableb` ?

Comment: Exactly. It is similar to the two tables A and B

Comment: cool.  my answer should be suitable in that case

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet?

Comment: Yes, I have. i used your method and it worked. i also tried using sub-select queries and i got the result too. However it is yours that I am using now. Thank you.

Comment: good to hear - if the answer helped can you click the accepted tick mark under the answer votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cross joining, which means matching every row against every other row. What you probably want is something like this, which guarantees one row per derived table, which means a cross join isn't going to break it in a way you dont want:

```
select a.total, b.total, c.total, a.total + b.total + c.total
  from
    (select sum(amount) total
       from tablea
    ) a
  join
    (select sum(amount) total
       from tableb
    ) b
  join
    (select sum(amount) total
       from tablec
    ) c
```

[demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36d8b/1)

Comment: just don't forget as `total` after each sum field. e.g. `sum(amount) as total`